# Recover values of <s:property > Struts

Tags: arrays, struts2

I have an

```
<s:property value="var"/>
```

`var` is an array of String and it returns a list of String.
How can i have the values of every component of the `<s:property.../>` separated?

Answer (score 0):

Use the for each loop in your jsp/html page.
An example:

```
<c:forEach var="var" items="${var}" varStatus="loopCounter">
<input type="text" name="var" value="<s:property value="${var}" />
```